# To which group of entities do `::` and `->` belong in Java?

Tags: java, operators, keyword

On https://github.com/winterbe/java8-tutorial I read, that `::` is a keyword; but i could not find it on:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

It was was also not in the list of operators
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

I thought `->` is a lambda operator,...

So if, `::` and `->` are neither keywords, nor operators, what are they?

Comment: `Copyright © 1995, 2015 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.` looks like you are looking at outdated page

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino: Is that a reason for downvoting?

Comment: who ever said it's duplicate ... answer given in link is not relevant

Comment: @Edward I didn't downvote you

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino : OK, sorry for suspecting you. I really don't understand why people vote questions down without writing a comment and explaining their decision. How can I learn what to improve the next time I ask a question?

Comment: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)